# Force Close After Implementation of Splash Screen w AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, forceclose

I'm getting a force close issue after attempting to implement a splash screen into my app.

The issue occurs on line 76  `lv.setAdapter(adapter);` however I'm unsure as to why.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

```
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at com.example.project1.MainActivity$MyTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:76)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at com.example.project1.MainActivity$MyTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4931)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
09-19 15:20:53.687: E/AndroidRuntime(25177):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

SOURCE:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView lv;
        final String URL = "http://news.google.com";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setContentView(R.layout.splash);
            lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            new MyTask().execute(URL);

        }

        private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog prog;
            String title = "";

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                prog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                prog.setMessage("Loading....");
                prog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                try {
                    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
                    Element tableHeader = doc.select("tr").first();

                    for (Element element : tableHeader.children()) {
                        aa.add(element.text().toString());
                    }

                    title = doc.title();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return title;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                prog.dismiss();
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to beat a dead horse but `lv` is `null` since you changed the `layout` with `setContentView()`. Maybe I can explain a little better why this is because I'm not sure you quite understand how `Views` work in the `Activity`.

When you call `setContentView()` it inflates the `xml layout` file that you set in this function. Initializing any `View` that is **not** in that `layout` file will return `null` which will give a `NPE` when you try to set a method on it such as `setAdapter()`.

It appears that you are under the assumption that you can still initialize the `ListView` which is in another `layout` file...you cannot. You can only use `Views` inflated with `setContentView()` or by inflating the `layout` file which holds that `View` and adding it to the currently inflated `layout.

One way around this is to call `setContentView()` again in `onPostExecute()` **then** initialize your `ListView` and set the `Adapter`. I wouldn't normally recommend calling `setContentView()` more than once in a single `Activity` but in your case it may be the easiest for what you currently have.

So it might look like this

```
  @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            prog.dismiss();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,aa);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: "Oh, oh, oh, it's magic, you know, / Never believe it's not so..."



Thanks CodeMagic! 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iiryJwvDtc

Comment: It did... thank you! (I was just waiting for the timer to expire)

Comment: Sorry for being pushy...its late in the day :/

Comment: No worries! 

P.S.

If you want another easy question to answer - I have another issue! : ) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904302/parsing-tablerow-data-from-correct-html-tags-via-jsoup-android

Comment: haHa! Awesome... (I thought you might get a kick out of that! This actually isn't the first time you've helped me before - thanks again!)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a View named `R.id.listView1` in `splash.xml`? It looks like you changed your `setContentView()` call to the splash screen, but your listview is on a more "main" page.

Answer (score 0):

`lv` is likely null here.  Have you verified in the debugger that it is getting set correctly when you set it to `(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);`?

Comment: The strange thing is it works fine until I changed setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); to   setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Comment: So yes... it is populated (until I changed the layout in order to display the splash screen until the values are retrieved by asynctask)

Comment: So `lv` is not included in `R.layout.splash` so it will be null if you try to get it through `findViewById`.

Answer (score 0):

Null Pointer Exception suggest that there might be problem with lv.
You have changed the name of xml.so verify whether *R.id.listview1 is present in splash.xml*